# NHibernate: Mapping class with generic enum property

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, enums, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class defined like this:

```
public class StateMachineMetadata<T> where T: struct
{
    public virtual int ID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual T State { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateChanged { get; set; }
}
```

Where the `State` property is an enum:

```
public enum CarState
{
    Stopped = 1,
    Moving = 2
}
public enum OrderState
{
    Ordered = 1,
    Delivered = 2
}
```

Can I have two types:

```
StateMachineMetadata<CarState>, StateMachineMetadata<OrderState>
```

to be persisted in **one** table `StateMachineMetadata` using NHibernate?

**=== update ===**

As workaround generic part can be moved to interface:

```
public interface IStateMachineMetadata<T> where T: struct
{
    int ID { get; }
    T State { get; set; }
    DateTime DateChanged { get; set; }
}

public class StateMachineMetadataBase
{
    public virtual int ID { get; protected set; }
    public virtual DateTime DateChanged { get; set; }
}

public class CarStateMachineMetadata
    : StateMachineMetadataBase, IStateMachineMetadata<CarState>
{
    public virtual CarState State { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, and here's why.

Let's assume we have two rows in the `StateMachineMetadata` table:

```
ID | State | DateChanged
1  |   1   |  2012-02-13
2  |   1   |  2012-02-14
```

If the `State` column is mapped both to `CarState` and `OrderState`, how would NHibernate determine which enum to deserialize to? One solution would be to add a *discriminator column* to the `StateMachineMetadata` table, which tells NHibernate which type it should map a specific row to.
For example the `Type` discriminator column:

```
ID | State | DateChanged | Type
1  |   1   |  2012-02-13    1
2  |   1   |  2012-02-14    2
```

tells NHibernate that the first row represents a `StateMachineMetadata<CarState>` while the second is a `StateMachineMetadata<OrderState>`. This is called a [Table per class hierarchy mapping](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-8-inheritance-mapping#8%282E%291%282E%291%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Table_per_class_hierarchy) in NHibernate. It requires both classes to inherit from a common base class, which in your case would naturally be `StateMachineMetadata<T>`.

But here's **the catch**: NHibernate *doesn't have a way to map a class with an open generic type*. The reason is that [it's simply not possible](http://ayende.com/blog/2951/nhibernate-and-generic-entities).

However, NHibernate *does* allow you to map classes with closed generics. You just can't map them to the same table. Here's how such configuration would look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
           assembly="MyAssembly"
           namespace="MyNamespace">
    <class name="StateMachineMetadata`1[MyNamespace.CarState]"
           table="StateMachineMetadata_CarState">
        <!-- property to column mappings -->
    </class>

    <class name="StateMachineMetadata`1[MyNamespace.OrderState]"
           table="StateMachineMetadata_OrderState">
        <!-- property to column mappings -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: @Jekas Did it answer your question?

Comment: Yep. But i still looking for solution, some workaround with IUserType may be.. or possibly it will work with concrete types.